# Retornar valores em ForeignKey e ManyToManyField em Django

Tags: python, django-1.8

Tenho os seguintes Models: Restaurante com um ForeignKey para Cardapio, Cardapio com um ManyToMany para Produto, Produto com um ManyToMany para DiaPromocao, e estou precisando no template, exibir algumas informações como por exemplo, o restaurante, o produto, o preço normal do produto e o preço promocional do produto. O restaurante e o produto consigo mostrar, através de um método que retorna os nomes dos produtos no model Cardapio, mas as outras informações com o preço normal e preço promocional do produto não consigo, alguém pode me dar uma ajuda aqui?

Segue link do gist com os modelos: https://gist.github.com/fandrefh/8f7d1bb5677857031c20

Answer (score 0):

Não acho uma boa ideia formatar a lista de produtos e preços no model, você pode fazer isso diretamente no template.

No template ficaria algo assim:

```
{% for produto in cardapio.produtos.all %}
    {{ produto }} {{ produto.preco_promocao }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado pela resposta, mas já havia tentado essa solução, vi isso em outros posts aqui mesmo o stackoverflow, mas não funciona comigo, talvez esteja fazendo algo de errado.